# How to append bunch of tags in existing XML using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a big xml file (2000 kb+) that I want to append using Python. I need to check to see if a tag with some value exists. If not I need to add a bunch of tags to the file at a particular position (before a tag)

Lets take this example, **restaurant.xml:**

```
<restaurant>
    <menu>
        <breakfast_menu>
            <food>          
                <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
                <price>$5.95</price>
                <description> Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
                <calories>650</calories>
            </food>
            <food>
                <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
                <price>$7.95</price>
                <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
                <calories>900</calories> 
            </food>
            <food>
                <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
                <price>$8.95</price>
                <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
                <calories>900</calories>
            </food>
        </breakfast_menu>
        <lunch_menu>
            blah...blah...blah
    </menu>
</restaurant>
```

1st step is to check if French Toast exists in xml file. If not, add the following before `</breakfast_menu>`

```
<food>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
    <calories>600</calories>
</food>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code given below

**EDIT:**

```
<restaurant>
    <menu>
        <breakfast_menu>
            <food>          
                <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
                <price>$5.95</price>
                <description> Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
                <calories>650</calories>
            </food>
            <food>
                <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
                <price>$7.95</price>
                <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
                <calories>900</calories> 
            </food>
            <food>
                <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
                <price>$8.95</price>
                <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
                <calories>900</calories>
            </food>
         </breakfast_menu>
    </menu>
</restaurant>
```

**Code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def SubElementWithText(parent, tag, text):
    attrib = {}
    element = parent.makeelement(tag, attrib)
    parent.append(element)
    element.text = text
    return element

def addXml(file, xpath_to_check, xpath_to_add_element, nodedict):
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    if root.findall(xpath_to_check):
        st = False
        for elem in root.findall(xpath_to_check):
            if elem.text == nodedict['name']:
                st = True
        if st == False:
            breakfast_menu = root.find(xpath_to_add_element)
            food = ET.SubElement(breakfast_menu, 'food')
            for element, value  in nodedict.items():
                SubElementWithText(food, element, value)
            tree.write(file)
            print("Elements added successfully")
        else:
            print("ELement already existed")

file = "restaurent.xml"
xpath_to_check = ".//food/name"
xpath_to_add_element = "./menu/breakfast_menu"
nodedict = {"name" : "French Toast", "price" : "$4.50", "description" : "Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread" , "calories" : "600" }
addXml(file, xpath_to_check, xpath_to_add_element, nodedict)
```

Comment: Thanks. elem.text == "French Toast"; is always returning false, even when it exists in the xml file. When I print elem.text, I do get "French Toast", and that should have returned True

Comment: If already element exist it will return true then you no need add the element right?

Comment: Check the xml whether it contains the "French Toast"